# Neovim format ruby code like rubocop

Tags: neovim, formatting, alignment

is there any chance to format code to satisfy rubocop?

By default my neovim is indenting code like that:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c,
    :d, :e, :f
end
```

However, it would be nicer to have it like that

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c,
                :d, :e, :f
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/) suits your needs?

E.g:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c,
    :d, :e, :f
end
```

typing `:Tabularize /:\a\S\s/l0` will result in

```
class Test
  attr_accessor:a, :b, :c,
               :d, :e, :f
end
```

`:Tabularize /:` aligns all colons. The colon must be followed by a letter (`\a`), a non whitespace character (`\S`) and a whitespace (`\s`). That complete match is then left-adjusted (`/l0`). The zero afterwards prevents Tabular to add whitespace after each alignment.

**note** that this is not permanent. I.e. when you reformat your code, the aligning is destroyed and it will look like the first example again. To make this aligning persistent, you could maybe define a custom formatting function which runs the above tabular command after the vim formatting. But I don't know much about that.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Looks like the best solutions would be to improve ruby plugin. Someone already lodged an issue https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/268